# Migrating existing maprdb into mongodb. springboot hadoop and maprdb used in the application

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, migrate, open-json

' My application used springboot hadoop and maprdb. I never used springhadoop and maprdb before. Please guide. I want to remove maprdb code and connect with mangodb.

```
my code is like this '

public static List<> getData(String a){
List<> DataList = new ArrayList<>();
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("ojai:mapr:");
try
{
DoctumentStore store = connection.getstore(table);

Query query = connection.newQuery().where(connection.newCondition()
          .matched("_id", code+"*"),build()).build();

DoctumentStream stream = store.find(query);

for(Document Doc : stream){
     ObjectMapper objectmapper = ObjectMapper();
     DataList.add(objectMapper.readValue(Doc.asJsonString(),abc.class));
}
store.close();
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
connection.close();
}
connection.close();
return DataList;
}

}
```